# Go functions dot notation

Tags: go

I want to build this:

```
finalResult, err := Function1(whatever type)
    .Function2(whatever type)
    .Function3(whatever type)
```

Something similar to promises in javascript but not necessarily the same concepts. Or similar to nested methods in Java. I just pretend avoid more code for the same tasks.

I don't want to do this :

```
result, err := new(Function1(whatever type)) //or *Function1(whatever type)
if err != nil {...}
result1, err := result.Function2(whatever type)
if err != nil {...}
finalResult, err := result1.Function3(whatever type)
if err != nil {...}
```

I've been trying with several options with structs and interfaces but I can't get any result.

My apology if I have a mistake in my grammar. I'm not still so good with my skill English.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the Fluent API design pattern. You return the same Object, or struct in Go, over and over.

This pattern does not allow you to return a tuple, or multiple return types though.  You can only return one object.

https://play.golang.org/p/9PceZwi1a3

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Object struct {
    Value string
    Error error
}

func (o *Object) Before(s string) *Object {
    o.Value = s + o.Value
    // add an error if you like
    // o.Error = error.New(...)
    return o
}

func (o *Object) After(s string) *Object {
    // could check for errors too
    if o.Error != nil {
        o.Value = o.Value + s
    }
    return o
}

func main() {
    x := Object{}

    x.
        Before("123").
        After("456").
        After("789").
        Before("0")

    if x.Error != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    fmt.Println(x.Value)
}
```

Edit: sberry's answer had a good idea.  Add an Error state on the `Object` struct itself which could allow u to check for errors in each func call.

---

Since you are new, please remember to evaluate all answers and mark the best one you believe lead you the answer.

Comment: so helpfull this response

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to have each `FunctionX` be a method on a receiver (most likely a pointer receiver if you are mutating state) and have them each return the receiver.  Like so

```
type someNumber struct {
    n int32
}

func (s *someNumber) Add(i int32) *someNumber {
    s.n += i
    return s
}

func (s *someNumber) Multiply(i int32) *someNumber {
    s.n *= i
    return s
}

func (s *someNumber) Subtract(i int32) *someNumber {
    s.n -= i
    return s
}

func main() {
    num := &someNumber{n: 0}
    result := num.Add(5).Multiply(4).Subtract(10)
    fmt.Println(result.n)
}
```

You could set and error on the `someNumber` as well, and check it at the end.

If you are looking to actually carry through the error, then you would need to do something like this.

```
func Function1(a int, err error) (int, error) {
    if err != nil {
        return a, err
    }
    return a, nil
}

func Function2(a int, err error) (int, error) {
    if err != nil {
        return a, err
    }
    return a*2, nil
}


func Function3(a int, err error) (int, error) {
    if err != nil {
        return a, err
    }
    return a*3, nil
}

func main() {
    a, err := Function3(Function2(Function1(1, nil)))
    fmt.Println(a, err) 
}
```

But, it seems like you are looking for the type of behavior an Error Monad would bring and that does not exist in Go.